# Inserting Image as blob not occuring

Tags: php, mysql

i have a piece of code which extracts the src of an  tag and then tries to save it in mysql

Here's the piece of code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($preview_url);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$image_src = $xp->query("//*[@class='cover-image']");
$cover_image_src = $image_src->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
echo $cover_image_src."-- ID --".$id."\n";
$update_offer_sql = "UPDATE aw_offers_v2 SET 
                    name = '$name', description = '$description', 
                    payout_type = '$payout_type', payout = '$payout',
                    expiration_date = '$expiration_time', 
                    preview_url = '$preview_url',tracking_url = '$tracking_url', 
                    categories = '$categories', countries = '$countries',
                    countries_short = '$countries_short', 
                    update_date = '$update_time', api_key = '$api',
                    network_id = '$api_url',
                    icon = '".mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($cover_image_src))."'
                            WHERE id = '$id'";
```

But when i am checking the database, i can see the field showing `BLOB 0 byte`

That means blob isnt being saved

How can i solve my problem?

Comment: what is the field type of icon?

Comment: BLOB.. The icon field is of BLOB datatype

Comment: I didnt mention the size. Do i need to mention the size. Could that be the reason its not working?

Comment: no need to mention the size. but plz check whether you are getting the data.

Comment: I am getting the data($cover_image_src) as anticipated... its just that the data is not getting inserted or updated in the database

Comment: 1. $cover_image_src have absolute and correct URL? If you insert this url to browser then image loaded?

Comment: yes, the $cover_image_src has correct URL. I can see them if i put in the address bar of browser... it also contains the absolute path

Comment: 2. Is file_get_contents($cover_image_src) work correct? It load file?  What output echo file_get_contents($cover_image_src); ?

Comment: echoing a hell lot of binary data

Answer (score -1):

mmmh are you sure to doing this sql request ? i dont see mysql_query on your code.

Try to show if your url is correct :

```
echo file_get_contents($cover_image_src);
```

Comment: This "answer" should be a comment.

Comment: @TecBrat Absolutely right bro. This should be a comment.

Comment: Check my profile, i dont have required reputation to comment 'You must have 50 reputation to comment' , sorry about this.

Other fields are well updated ?